# Running Edge.js from an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, asp.net-mvc-4, edge.js

I'm having an interesting time trying to get Edge.js running from an ASP.NET MVC project.  From the Edge documentation, the basic console application is this:

```
public static async Task Start()
{
    var func = Edge.Func(@"
    return function (data, callback) {
        callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
    }");

    Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Start().Wait();
}
```

and this works with no problem on my machine.  The next step is to create an ASP.NET MVC project, and to try to run the same script from a form-driven controller action.  The ASP.NET MVC project runs on IIS Express by default.

This is the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TestEdge()
    {
        try
        {
            var func = Edge.Func(@"
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
            }");

            Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the call to `Edge.Func` blows up.  The exception is

```
System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in EdgeJs.dll
Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'node.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I have Edge installed globally (via npm install edge -g).

I have tried copying the `node.dll` file directly into the bin folder, but that generates a BadImageFormat exception.

According to the Edge.js documentation, "Using Node.js via Edge.js in ASP.NET web applications is no different than in a .NET console application".  However, this is the simplest possible implementation in an ASP.NET application, so there must be some difference.  As per the suggestion in the documentation, I also tried copying the `node_modules` subdirectory into the `bin` folder of the web app, but this did not help.

Any further suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the Edge.js NuGet package fixed this for me.

To migrate from IIS Express to IIS, you'll need an installation of [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode).